# How do I solve equation $\bar{z} = |z|$ correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm having troubles, finding how solution would look like for complex equation of the form $\bar{z} = |z|$. Taking $z = x + iy$, we get the following:
$$x - iy = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2},$$
then raising it to the 2nd power we get
$$x^2 - 2ixy - y^2 = x^2 + y^2,$$
$$2y^2 = -2ixy.$$
Now, taking complex terms as one equation and real as second, we construct the system of equations:
$$-2xy = 0$$
$$2y^2 = 0$$
Which again yields equation:
$$y^2 + xy = 0.$$
Here we get that $\Im{(z)} = 0$. But what is $\Re{(z)}$ equal to?

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Looks ok. Wouldn't the real part just be the modulus at that point? At which point it would have to be positive.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: It should be $\bar z = \sqrt{z\bar z}$, not $\bar z = z\bar z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From $2y^2 = 0$, you have $y=0$ or $\Im(z) = 0$.  But then you have the problem that $x$ can be anything.  This is because by squaring the first equation, you "threw away" the information that the solutions require $x \geq 0$.  (I.e., $x^2 = |x|^2$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.)

You would be better served working with $z = r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ with $r \in \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$.  Then $$ r = |z| = \overline{z} = r \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta}  \text{.}  $$  If $r=0$, we have the solution $z=0$.  If $r \neq 0$, we can divide through, getting $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta} = 1$, so $\theta = 2 \pi k$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.  That is, $z \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$.

Gluing the two solution sets together, we have $z \in \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Answer (score 13):

$|z|$ is real and nonnegative.  Therefore, so is $\overline{z}$.  I.e., $\overline{z}$ is a number on the nonnegative real semiaxis, and, conversely, every such number equals its own modulus.

Comment: May I ask You to write this reasoning more "rigorously"? :-) I got the $|z|$ point, because it gives us a real number, which is always positive. But why is $\bar{z}$ then always positive?

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity $\lvert z \rvert$ is real and *nonnegative*, therefore so is $\bar{z}$.

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity keep in mind that your solutions are $z \in \mathbb C$ so that $|z| = \bar{z}$. So any property of $|z|$ is a property of $\bar{z}$ for these $z$.

Comment: "But why is z¯ then always positive?"

Nonnegative, as user4894 pointed out.  And, $\overline{z}$ is then always nonnegative because, in the conditions of your problem, it is equal to $|z|$.

Comment: @avs: There are countries (France, fir instance) where ‘positive’ means ‘non-negative’, and positive is said ‘strictly positive’.

Comment: @Bernard, right, forgot about that.  Vl. Arnol'd severely criticized the French for doing that.  According to this terminology, $0$ is also a "positive" number.:)  However, I could not really make any assumptions about the Asker's interpretation of that term, and tried to make my comment as unambiguous as I could.